# Stop query animation after X cycles

Tags: jquery, animation

Can't find this anywhere - or I'm looking for the question incorrectly
I have an animation running in query and the client wants it to stop after a few run throughs I thought it best to declare variable, add to it and stop when it's run through X cycles but don't have a clue how to do that. Here's the basic principle

```
$(function(){ titles(); });

function titles() {
var cycles = 0;
// ANIMATION START SCRIPT IS IN HERE
}

function titleSlider() {
var cycles = cycles + 1;

// ANIMATION SCRIPT IS IN HERE

if (cycles = 10) { stop };
}
```

Comment: How does the recursion happen, if it animates over and over again, there has to be some sort of recursion, and without seeing that, there's no way to tell you how to stop that recursion after a number of iterations

Comment: @adeneo you can do that by not initiating the call unless the promise is fulfilled in a previous call, this would sort of fake sequential structure.

Comment: @OQX - that's just fine if it uses promises, but there's many ways to create recursion, hence the comment and why the OP should post the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

using promises would solve this, you can just defer animation call inside the function and on done call the same function after checking the 10 cycles

```js
$(function () {
    titles();
});

function titles() {
    var cycles = 0;
    var titleSlider = function () {
        cycles++;

        $('#test').fadeOut({
            "opacity": "0"
        }, 1000).promise().done(function () {
            if (cycles < 10) {
                titleSlider();
            }
        });
        $('#test').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
        console.log(cycles)
    }
    titleSlider();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="test">test</h1>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L133hj0r/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function titles() {
    var cycles = 0;
    // ANIMATION START SCRIPT IS IN HERE

    function titleSlider() {
        cycles += 1;

        // ANIMATION SCRIPT IS IN HERE
        $('target element').animate({/*animation properties*/}, function(){
            if(cycles != 10){
                titleSlider();
            }
        });
    }

    titleSlider();   
}
```